# Rounded Corner for a Polygon (hexagon)

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to achieve a rounded corner hexagon ImageView on Android

Exactly like this one but Hexagon :

[image]

I tried my best but failed in every possible way, i did find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24770675/2040750) answer which is perfect as it lets u enter number of sides required and it does the rest. but sadly it was for iOS, so i am not sure if it is helpful to anyone that know both languages, and can recreate it in android

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a library that can accomplish that but that was after i done it myself, So here is the [link](https://github.com/siyamed/android-shape-imageview) to library and it does many shapes

Answer (score 0):

use [this](https://github.com/AlbertGrobas/PolygonImageView) lib

> this can be helpful for you . i used this and made just like yours.