# how to draw hexagonal image in a UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I have created a dynamic page in order to show profiles of the user. For that i have used collection view cell, what i want is that i have to represent those profiles in a numeric manner and that too inside a hexagon shaped image. Kindly can anyone give me some ideas how to do it. Am pretty much confused. Here is the screenshot of how the dynamic page should look like. [image]

Comment: It wasn't difficult to find a solution with a simple Google search? http://stackoverflow.com/a/24770675/2507277

Answer (score 0):

Solution is very simple. Just use `UIImageView` with hexagonal `image.jpg` just like shown in above cells, and show `UILabel` over `UIImaeView`, which shows Number in white font.